# Replace comma(,) with and in JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

**Input:**

```json
{
  "ratings":["1","2"]
}
```

I need to replace this comma to and using JOLT. Is this possible in JOLT??

**Expected Output:**

```json
{
  "ratings": "1 and 2"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes possible, you can use **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation along with string concatenation function **join** such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join(' and ',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```

or prefer only

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "ratings": "=join(' and ',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```

for only one individual key-value pair(if there are *more than one* lists)

**Edit** : In the case, you have an array with unsorted elements, and converting to the desired concatenated string after sorting whenever presumingly you use it within Apache-Nifi, then add two **JoltTransformJSON** processor, perform the below operation within the first processor ;

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "ratings": "=sort(@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```

then apply one of the cases with the **join** function as the second step.

Comment: Can i sort the input before doing the join operation. i have tried it but it is not working. Can u suggest any solution for this issue.

Comment: I think you can ask another question which expresses clearly what you mean @Yugi , I'll be get in touch.

Comment: I need to sort the input first 
from this
{
  "ratings":["2","1"]
}
to like this
{
  "ratings":["1","2"]
}
Then apply join on the sorted result.
Expeted Output:
{
"ratings":"1 and 2"
}

Comment: @Yugi will you use it within the Apache NiFi ?

Comment: Barbaros Özhan yes i will use it Apache Nifi